# download companywise s&p 500 stock price data in R

Tags: r, download, quantmod, stock, price

I can download companywise s&p 500 stock price data by using this code

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols(c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOGL"), auto.assign = TRUE, from = "2005-01-05",src="google")
```

Now it is diffiult to type all 500 tickers like "MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOGL" this. Is there any solution to avoid this.

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/18835

Answer (score 1):

use tidyquant library
`tq_index("SP500")` 
`tq_get_stock_index_options` gives you indexes you can download 
https://github.com/business-science/tidyquant

Comment: If you'd like to get the historical stock prices for all stocks: `tq_index("SP500") %>% tq_get(get = "stock.prices")`